# SurfaceView Width/Height

Tags: android

Я делаю игру и использую SurfaceView для прорисовок объектов и в методе SurfaceChanged я получаю высоту и ширину View. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    mViewWidth = width;
    mViewHeight = height;
    System.out.println(mViewWidth+" "+mViewHeight);
}
```

Получается, что ширина и высота View 320x403. Но разрешение моего экрана 320x240. Как это возможно!?

Answer (score 2):

Размеры вида не привязаны к размерам физического экрана: можно создать вид как меньше, так и больше экрана. Вид шире экрана прокручивается по горизонтали, а вид длиннее экрана - по вертикали.

Кроме того, возможно, SurfaceView возвращает не пиксели, а дипы (пиксели = дипы * (плотность / 160));

Comment: Но тут такое дело, я указываю координаты объекта (0,320) для прорисовки. Я ожидаю что он будет в самом низу экрана, но он не в самом низу экрана. Если указать координаты(0,400) то будет у самого экрана. Как это понять?

Comment: Можно попробовать: LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height); surfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);